# service and marketing cloud resources for Dev 401

Tags: force.com, certification, dev401

I'm prepping the 401, and was told that the exam included content from the service and marketing clouds. I didn't study that stuff, I've only done the sales cloud.  I couldn't find much online that taught you about these clouds it's not included in the force.com fundamentals book

Does anyone have a pointer to some resources? Again, the purpose is to know enough for the 401

Comment: Have you checked the study guide to see what topics are covered - the study guide should cover all the topics you need to study certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedDeveloper.pdf

Comment: I think you will be better off just going over the resources we have available for the Developer certification already. I don't remember anything specific to the Service Cloud/Marketing on the Dev 401 exam. It is much more focused on custom objects, permissions, etc.

Comment: I've been to that page. My boss said stuff like consoles, and mini page layout were on his exam. those were'nt really in the fundamentals book...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been to [this page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Certification) which should have the latest link to the material you'll need? It also has a link to the [Spring '13 Study Guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedDeveloper.pdf?v=7&SiteID=0DM30000000PBPx) and many other study resources.

There are a number of other sites that also have sample tests like [Salesforce.com Tips and Tricks](http://salesforcecertification.blogspot.in/2012/01/hi-guys-alright-now-guys-here-are-some.html), [All About Salesforce](http://allaboutsalesforce.blogspot.com/) and the [Getting Started Page Free Page](http://certifiedondemand.com/salesforce-com-certified-administrator-getting-started/) of Certified on Demand.com.

Comment: I've been to that page. My boss said stuff like consoles, and mini page layout were on his exam. those were'nt really in the fundamentals book

Comment: In terms of page layouts, most everyone I've spoken to will tell you to focus on the tutorial that builds the Recruiting App. The majority of questions tend to relate to that particular tutorial. Of course, YMMV on that one.;)

Comment: Browse/google through the help and documentation (implementation guides) based on the certification study guide. Try to set up things in a dev org so you get a good feeling of things.

Comment: Yes, SF expects someone to practice in a Dev Org or gain experience someplace and not just to go through the workbooks. The mini page layouts are just another option or feature that's used on the page layout screen for accomplishing a desired task.